# How to redirect traffic to my local IP when I use Windows hotspot?

Tags: windows, login, redirection, hotspot, captive-portal

I have created a hotspot on my Windows PC. I want all my traffic trying to access any URL to my local IP (where I am serving some login pages via XAMPP). Can anyone tell how to accomplish this manually or via some piece of software (only for redirection).

I want functionality like Captive Portal but only redirection part, not all this login thing. that's why I can't use a Captive Portal software.

Comment: @Someguy: You put your bounty on a very vaguely-written post. You had better clarify your problem better than it's written here.